# Conexão PHP - Lumen

Tags: php, mysql, lumen

Estou aprendendo PHP com Lumen e me deparei num problema na string de conexão da api.

Estou com o mysql instalado e consigo utilizá-lo normalmente via workbench. Quando eu clico para ver as informações de conexão, aparece uma informação de que o nome do Host é `INT-WKS10`. Porém, quando eu rodo o comando abaixo:

```
select user,host from mysql.user
```

Eu obtenho o resultado:

```
sa                  %
mysql.infoschema    localhost

mysql.session       localhost

mysql.sys           localhost

root                localhost
```

Já tentei várias configurações. Quando eu configuro o DB_HOST com localhost, recebo o seguinte erro:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL:
```

Quando eu utilizo o INT-WKS10, obtenho o erro:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'INT-WKS10.integro.inf.br' (using password: YES)
```

Abaixo minha conexão

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=agendamento
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

Comment: Acredito que o seu problema seja criar um usuário com todos os privilégios no banco, ao invés de usar o root.

Comment: Eu fiz isso e não funcionou. Será que tem a ver com o tipo da autenticação? As opções são standard, SHA256 Password ou caching_sha2_password.

Comment: O usuário root só tem acesso via localhost, e você aparentemente está tentando acessar de outro computador. Você precisa criar um usuário que tenha permissão tipo o usuário sa ali, que tem permissão % -> qualquer origem

Comment: Estou acessando a base na minha máquina local

Comment: Mas o banco está em sua máquina local?

Comment: Consegui! Obrigada! Eu criei um usuário semelhante ao sa e coloquei o tipo de conexão standard.

Comment: E sim. o DB é local

Comment: Vou escrever a resposta, marque como respondida, ok? Você fez o que eu disse, ou o que o Rafael Mena disse?

Comment: `INT-WKS10.integro.inf.br` é uma hospedagem? Se sim, você deve ter um painel e nesse painel para o mysql dentro da hospedagem ele cria um usuario e senha para ti, que **não** é o "root" ... Se for outro pc na sua rede, ai tem que conversar com quem instalou o mysql para ver qual usuario é o usado. PS: para a maioria das coisas "root" é um exagero, em aplicações comuns e até avançadas geralmente não precisamos de acesso "root", root é algo apenas interessante a quem faz manutenção no banco geral e tem permissão para isto.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que o seu problema seja criar um usuário com todos os privilégios no banco, ao invés de usar o root.

Por mais que a sua conexão seja local, sua aplicação exige que o usuário seja standard não default (root).